# Stop Windows 8.1 from removing Grub

Tags: linux, windows-8.1, grub, secure-boot

I've got a relatively new HP Envy machine running Windows 8.1 that I want to run Ubuntu on. Installation works great and I'm all happy until I boot back into Windows, at which point grub is removed and I no longer have access to booting into my Linux partition.

I can boot off of a live CD and fix grub, but this only works until the next reboot.

I've gone into the BIOS and disabled SecureBoot, which was on when I purchased the computer. Is there anything else that needs to be done to stop Windows from "fixing" the boot loader? I don't want to get rid of Windows completely as I do use it, but for day-to-day work I want to use Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You might also need to enable 'legacy mode' as well as disabling Secure Boot. I don't work with HP much, but with Dells and Lenovos it means that UEFI has to be disabled and Legacy enabled.

Comment: Can you expand upon this answer to explain how this would address the question?